# Why Gumbel softmax and not other types of softmax?

Tags: sampling, softmax, gumbel-distribution

Ignore the method name. Is there a reason why in the Gumbel softmax trick we sample from Gumbel distribution? Since we are doing something similar to a reparameterization trick, can't we just sample from a normal distribution? I know Gumbel distribution are use to deal with extreme values, is this why we use Gumbel distribution to sample and not other type of distribution?

Comment: https://sassafras13.github.io/GumbelSoftmax/